Real-time message not displaying on receiver side in Flutter app using Pusher
'm working on a real-time chat application in Flutter using Pusher for real-time communication. The issue is that when I send a message, it does not appear on the receiver's side in real-time, even though the connection is successfully established and the event is being triggered.
Here is the console log:
[log] Connection state changed: CONNECTING
[log] Connection state changed: CONNECTED
[log] Subscription succeeded: chat.d59adb49-cd8f-46a7-8237-c955a00a8966_3ca57ba0-7695-4d20-8469-37f713fc8d05 Data: {}
[log] event came: {}
[log] event name: pusher:subscription_succeeded

pusher configuration :
class PusherConfig {
  late PusherChannelsFlutter _pusher;


  String APP_ID ="1862571";
  String API_KEY ="659ba3cdeea747614342";
  String SECRET ="7959737c2c26900cb335";
  String API_CLUSTER ="ap1";


  // Tambahkan getter untuk mengakses _pusher dari luar kelas
  PusherChannelsFlutter get pusher => _pusher;


  Future<void> initPusher(Function(PusherEvent) onEvent, {String channelName = "chat", String? roomId}) async {
    _pusher = PusherChannelsFlutter.getInstance();


    try {
      await _pusher.init(
        apiKey: API_KEY,
        cluster: API_CLUSTER,
        onConnectionStateChange: onConnectionStateChange,
        onError: onError,
        onSubscriptionSucceeded: onSubscriptionSucceeded,
        onEvent: onEvent,
        onSubscriptionError: onSubscriptionError,
        onDecryptionFailure: onDecryptionFailure,
        onMemberAdded: onMemberAdded,
        onMemberRemoved: onMemberRemoved,
        onAuthorizer: onAuthorizer,
      );


      try {
        if (roomId != null) {
          await _pusher.subscribe(channelName: "$channelName.$roomId");          
          log("Subscribed to:  $channelName.$roomId");
        } else {
          await _pusher.subscribe(channelName: channelName);
          log("Subscribed to:  $channelName");
        }
      } catch (e) {
        log("Subscription error: ${e.toString()}");
      }


      await _pusher.connect();
    } catch (e) {
      log("Initialization error: $e");
    }
  }


  void disconnect() {
    _pusher.disconnect();
  }


  void unsubscribe(String channelName) {
    _pusher.unsubscribe(channelName: channelName);
  }


  // Event handler methods
  void onConnectionStateChange(dynamic currentState, dynamic previousState) {
    log("Connection state changed: $currentState");
  }


  void onError(String message, int? code, dynamic e) {
    log("Error: $message Code: $code Exception: $e");
  }


  void onEvent(PusherEvent event) {
    log("Event received: $event");
  }


  void onSubscriptionSucceeded(String channelName, dynamic data) {
    log("Subscription succeeded: $channelName Data: $data");
  }


  void onSubscriptionError(String message, dynamic e) {
    log("Subscription error: $message Exception: $e");
  }


  void onDecryptionFailure(String event, String reason) {
    log("Decryption failure: $event Reason: $reason");
  }


  void onMemberAdded(String channelName, PusherMember member) {
    log("Member added: $channelName Member: $member");
  }


  void onMemberRemoved(String channelName, PusherMember member) {
    log("Member removed: $channelName Member: $member");
  }


  dynamic onAuthorizer(
      String channelName, String socketId, dynamic options) async {
    var authUrl = "${GlobalVariables.baseUrl}/broadcasting/auth";
    var result = await http.post(
      Uri.parse(authUrl),
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ${await LoginLocalDatasource().getToken()}',
      },
      body: 'socket_id=' + socketId + '&channel_name=' + channelName + '',
    );
      log('authUrl: $authUrl');
      log('result: ${result.body}');
    var json = jsonDecode(result.body);
    return json;
   
  }
}

chat room code :
class ChatRoom extends StatefulWidget {
  final String? uuidReceiver;
  final String? uuidSender;
  final String? nama;
  final bool? isDosen;


  const ChatRoom({
    Key? key,
    this.uuidReceiver,
    this.uuidSender,
    this.nama,
    this.isDosen,
  }) : super(key: key);


  @override
  State<ChatRoom> createState() => _ChatRoomState();
}


class _ChatRoomState extends State<ChatRoom> {
  TextEditingController messageController = TextEditingController();
  ScrollController scrollController = ScrollController();
  late PusherConfig pusherConfig;
  GetChatDsnResponseModel? chatDetailsDsnModel;
  String _log = 'output:\n'; // Tambahkan variabel log
  final String eventName = "MessageSent";
  List<ChatDsn> getChatDosen = [];
  List<Chat> getChatMhs = [];
  Timer? _timer;


  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();


   // Inisialisasi Pusher
    initilizeRoom('${widget.uuidSender}_${widget.uuidReceiver}');
    // context.read<ChatBloc>().add(ChatEvent.getChatDsn(widget.uuidReceiver!));
    context.read<ChatBloc>().add(ChatEvent.getDetailChatDsn(widget.uuidReceiver!));
    // context.read<ChatBloc>().add(ChatEvent.getChatMhs(widget.uuidSender!));
    // _timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 2), (timer) {
    //   _refreshChat(); // Panggil fungsi refresh chat setiap 2 detik
    // });
  }


 




  initilizeRoom(String roomID) async {
    pusherConfig = PusherConfig();


    pusherConfig.initPusher(
      onEvent,
      roomId: roomID,
    );
  }


  void animateListToTheEnd({int time = 500}) {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      // Pastikan ScrollController memiliki klien sebelum menggulir
      if (scrollController.hasClients) {
        scrollController.animateTo(
          scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent,
          duration: Duration(milliseconds: time),
          curve: Curves.easeInOut,
        );
      }
    });
  }


  void onEvent(PusherEvent event) {
    log("event came: " + event.data.toString());
    log("event name: " + event.eventName.toString());


    try {
      // Cek apakah event yang datang adalah "MessageSent"
      if (event.eventName == r"MessageSent") {
        print('Handling MessageName event: ${event.data}');
        // Pastikan event.data adalah Map dan bukan String
        final Map<String, dynamic> eventData = jsonDecode(event.data);


        // Log untuk melihat struktur data yang diterima
        log("Parsed event data: $eventData");


        // Jika "message" berada di dalam "data"
        if (eventData.containsKey("data")) {
          ChatDsn? message =
              ChatDsn.fromJson(eventData["data"]); // Parsing message dari JSON
          setState(() {
            chatDetailsDsnModel!.data.add(message); // Tambahkan ke daftar chat
          });
          context.read<ChatBloc>().add(ChatEvent.addLocalMessageDsn(message));
         
        }
      }
      setState(() {});
      animateListToTheEnd();
    } catch (e) {
      log(e.toString());
    }
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocConsumer<ChatBloc, ChatState>(
      listener: (context, state) {
        state.maybeWhen(
          orElse: () {},
          loading: () {},
          loadedDetailDsn: (dataChatDsn) async {
            final uuid = dataChatDsn.data!.uuid;


              // Beri sedikit delay untuk memastikan state sudah terupdate
              await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 500));
              log("Detail loaded, calling getChatDsn with uuid: $uuid");
              context.read<ChatBloc>().add(ChatEvent.getChatDsn(widget.uuidReceiver!));
             
          },
          loadedChatDsn: (getChatDsn) {
            log('Chat Dsn successfully loaded');
           
          },
          error: (message) {
            log("Error in state: $message");
          },
        );
      },
      builder: (context, state) {
        return Scaffold(
              appBar: AppBar(
                backgroundColor: Colors.teal,
                leading: IconButton(
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
                  onPressed: () {
                    context.pop();
                    context.read<ChatBloc>().add(ChatEvent.getUserMhs());
                  },
                ),
                title: Row(
                  children: [
                    const CircleAvatar(
                      backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                          'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1438761681033-6461ffad8d80?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1170&q=80'),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(width: 10),
                    Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          widget.nama!,
                          style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                actions: [
                  IconButton(
                    icon: const Icon(Icons.more_vert),
                    onPressed: () {},
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              body: Column(
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: BlocConsumer<ChatBloc, ChatState>(
                        listener: (context, state) {
                          state.mapOrNull(
                            loadedChatDsn: (getChatDosen) {
                            print('ini loaded chat dosen');
                            setState(() {
                              // Update the getChatDosen list with new data from Bloc
                              this.getChatDosen = getChatDosen.dataChatDsn.data;
                            });
                            animateListToTheEnd();
                          }, loadedChatMhs: (getChatMhs) {
                            print('ini loaded chat mhs');
                            // initilizeRoom('${widget.uuidSender}_${widget.uuidReceiver}');
                            animateListToTheEnd();
                          });
                        },
                        builder: (context, state) {
                              return ListView.builder(
                                controller: scrollController,
                                itemCount: getChatDosen.length,
                                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                  bool isSender =
                                      getChatDosen[index].senderUuid ==
                                          widget.uuidSender;
                                  // print('isSender: ${getChatDosen.data[index].senderUuid} vs ${widget.uuidSender}');
                                  return ChatBubble(
                                    isSender: isSender,
                                    text: getChatDosen[index].message,
                                    mediaUrl: getChatDosen[index].mediaPath !=
                                            null
                                        ? "${GlobalVariables.baseUrl}/${getChatDosen[index].mediaPath}"
                                        : null,
                                  );
                                },
                              );
                           
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  // Input field and send button
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 0),
                    child: Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                      decoration: const BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white),
                      child: Row(
                        children: [
                          IconButton(
                            icon: const Icon(Icons.camera_alt),
                            onPressed: () async {
                              // Implementasi aksi kamera
                            },
                          ),
                          Expanded(
                            child: TextField(
                              controller: messageController,
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                hintText: 'Pesan...',
                                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                                  borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                                ),
                                filled: true,
                                fillColor: Colors.grey[200],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          BlocConsumer<ChatBloc, ChatState>(
                            listener: (context, state) {
                              state.maybeWhen(
                                orElse: () {},
                                loadedChatDsn: (dataChatDsn) {
                                  initilizeRoom(
                                      "${widget.uuidSender}_${widget.uuidReceiver}");
                                  animateListToTheEnd();
                                },
                                loadedChatMhs: (dataChatMhs) {
                                  print('ini loaded chat mhs');


                                  // context.read<ChatBloc>().add(
                                  //     ChatEvent.getChatMhs(widget.uuidSender!));
                                  animateListToTheEnd();
                                },
                              );
                            },
                            builder: (context, state) {
                              return IconButton(
                                icon: const Icon(Icons.send),
                                onPressed: () {
                                  final requestData = AddChatDsnRequestModel(
                                    uuidReceiver: widget.uuidReceiver!,
                                    message: messageController.text,
                                    media: null,
                                  );




                                  // Trigger the event through Pusher
                                  // initilizeRoom('${widget.uuidSender}_${widget.uuidReceiver}');
                                 
                                  // Simpan pesan yang baru dikirim di local list agar segera tampil
                                  setState(() {
                                    getChatDosen.add(ChatDsn(
                                      receiverUuid: widget.uuidReceiver!,
                                      senderUuid: widget.uuidSender!,
                                      message: messageController.text,
                                      mediaPath: null, // Jika ada media, tambahkan di sini
                                    ));
                                  });


                                  // Trigger the Pusher event here
                                  pusherConfig.pusher.trigger(
                                    PusherEvent(
                                      channelName: 'chat${widget.uuidSender}_${widget.uuidReceiver}', // Pastikan channel yang sesuai
                                      eventName: eventName,
                                      data: jsonEncode({
                                        'message': messageController.text,
                                        'media': null,
                                        'receiver_uuid': widget.uuidReceiver,
                                      }),
                                      userId: widget.uuidSender
                                    ),
                                  );


                                  messageController.clear();
                                 
                                  context
                                      .read<ChatBloc>()
                                      .add(ChatEvent.addChatDsn(requestData));
                                },
                              );
                            },
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            );
       
      },
    );
  }
}


I ensured that the connection with Pusher was established successfully by checking the console logs, which showed the connection state changing to CONNECTED.

I verified that the channel subscription was successful by logging the subscription event and confirming that the subscription_succeeded even


